# jPlayer does not cache the media while playing, if output is provided by PHP script

Tags: php, jquery, jplayer

In other words: it does not cache rest of the song while it's playing.

JS:

```
$('#jplayer-9999').jPlayer({
    ready: function() {
        $(this).jPlayer('setMedia', {
            oga: 'http://mysite/getogg.php',
        }).jPlayer('play', 15);

        $(this).bind($.jPlayer.event.timeupdate, function(event) {
            if(event.jPlayer.status.currentTime > 55) {
                $(this).jPlayer('play', 15);
            }
        });

    },
    play: function() {
        $(this).jPlayer('pauseOthers');
    },
    cssSelectorAncestor: '#jp_container_9999',
    swfPath: '/js/jplayer',
    supplied: 'oga',
    preload: 'auto'
});
```

PHP (getogg.php):

```
<?php

header('Content-type: audio/ogg');
$output = readfile("/oggs/1234.ogg");

echo $output;

?>
```

However direct links work just fine and song is caching:
oga: 'http://mysite/oggs/1234.ogg'

Please help resolving this issue.

Comment: do you mean progressive buffering? also just spitting the entire file out like may cause the issue not to mention high memory usage you should set the correct cache headers and spit out smaller chunks with fgets and clear the buffer

Comment: @LawrenceCherone: Sounds reasonable, can you provide the example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was related to OGG format.
Changing media to MP3 fixed an issue.

Answer (score 1):

Try This:

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);

$status=stream("./oggs/1234.ogg");

if($status !== true){
    if($status=='1'){echo('Cannot stream a folder check path!');}
    if($status=='2'){echo('File not found!');}
}

function stream($file,$speed=1024){
    if (file_exists($file)) {
        if(is_dir($file)){return '1';}
        header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
        header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
        header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="'.basename($file).'"');
        header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
        header('Connection: Keep-Alive');
        header('Expires: 0');
        header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0');
        header('Pragma: public');
        header('Content-Length: '.sprintf("%u", filesize($file)));

        ob_clean();
        $handle = fopen($file, "rb");
        $chunksize=(sprintf("%u", filesize($file))/$speed);

        set_time_limit(0);
        while (!feof($handle)) {
            echo fgets($handle, $chunksize);
            flush();
        }
        fclose($handle);
        return true;
    }else{
        return '2';
    }
    return;
}
?>
```

Comment: @Radio ok, try it now, visit the script directly

Comment: Sorry, browser glitch, restarted, File not found, forgot it's Windows, needed '../' instead of './'. Browser is getting the stream, can play in VLC and Winamp, but not in jPlayer.